# Why isn't the static constructor hit first?

Tags: c#, .net, constructor, static

I have the below code and I have only two simple questions which are normal to expect in the behavior of the program below, which I am not seeing unfortunately:

1. Static constructor in any class should be the first one to be hit soon after static fields being hit. Then only instance constructor. But what I am seeing is, the debug first goes to the public constructor. Sad thing. Why?

Although: the output of the program is:

> This is Staticcc...
>
> 1

...Which is correct.

2. I kept a break point in the Static constructor start, but when I debug it only shows break point in the end brace of static constructor. Why?

Sample code:

```
public sealed class B  : A, C
{
    public   int? m = 0;
    public B()
    {
        m = 1;
    }
    private B(int a, int b)
    {
        m = 2;
    }
    protected B(int x, int y, int z)
    {
        m = 3;
    }       

    static B()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("THis is staticcc");
    }

    public static B b = new B();
    public static B BC
    {
        get
        {
            return b;
        }
    }

    static void Main()
    {           
        Console.WriteLine(B.BC.m);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public interface C
{
}

public  class A 
{
    //private A()
    //{

    //}       
}
```

Comment: As an aside, why have you included two unused constructors and an interface and a base class? They're irrelevant to your question - try to keep examples minimal.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Sure, I was trying to learn about static class, singleton etc etc and difference between these etc, so it was a mess :) Sorry... Meanwhile these observations popped into my mind :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
public static B b = new B();
```

Static field initializers are executed *before* the static constructor is executed. From the C# spec section 10.5.5.1:

> If a static constructor (10.12) exists in the class, execution of the static field initializers occurs immediately prior to executing that static constructor.

Your static field initializer calls your instance constructor, therefore the instance constructor is the first thing to execute.

> Although: the output of the program is This is Staticcc... then 1...Which is correct.

Yes, because all of the initialization happens as part of evaluating `B.BC.m` in `Main`.

If you add `Console.WriteLine("Instance Constructor");` into your constructor, you'll see:

```
Instance Constructor
THis is staticcc
1
```

If that doesn't help, think of `Main` as being this:

```
int tmp = B.BC.m;       // This prints initialization bits
Console.WriteLine(tmp); // This prints 1
```

Comment: Thank you Jon, I am learning. I now understand it because I call new B(). Agree. However, irrespective of explicit forcing like this, the behavior should be Static constructor should be executed before any instance constructor? Is that not the way it is said about static contructor execution? Now, another question that pops in my mind is, why the output is correct? If you say instance is executed first, then I should see output as "1, then This is Staticc"...right?

Comment: "the behavior should be Static constructor should be executed before any instance constructor" - not if you call the instance constructor from a static field initializer, no.

Comment: @Deevinee: And no, the output is correct because `Console.WriteLine` is in your `Main` method. If you add logging into your instance constructor, you'll see what's going on.

Comment: Jon, thank you. Sorry again for silly question, why the breakpoints when I keep on starting brace in Static ctor, doesn't show while executing/debugging using F5 but it displays breakpoint in ending brace. Any clue? I am confused; But when I break the execution and see, it displays breakpoint I set in start and the ending brace doesn't have breakpoint, which is cool

Comment: @Deevinee: I suggest you ask a new question (with a bit more clarity) for the debugging-specific bits. Keep questions to one per post - I've explained the behaviour of your code from a C# perspective.

Comment: Agree with Jon. The code works as documented. Debugger related questions are totally different and sometimes very version specific, so I would suggest to create a new post with the specific information on the debugger version used.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Thank you. Well I am again confused, when you introduced a print inside Instance constructor. Why again "Instance Constructor"? I would expect asTHis is staticcc, then 1, then instance constructor(The last two can be of any order based on how I keep in instance constructor) but why it is not happening?

Comment: @Deevinee: I'm not sure how many different ways I can say it: static field initializers are executed before the code in your static constructor, and your static field initializer calls the instance constructor... so the instance constructor executes first. It's really that simple.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Thank you so much, I now understand it :) I debugged slowly and referenced all your points, agree :) Thank you so much for your time. I was also reading aa thread you wrote on Static class/singleton difference topics :)

Answer (score 1):

That is because this line is ran before the `static` constructor:

```
public static B b = new B();
```

Your first line in the `static` constructor (the part you don't see, but is actually there) is actually calling the constructor of `B`. That is the reason you don't see the `static` constructor hit first.

If you would write it like this, you would see the `static` constructor hit first:

```
static B()
{
    Console.WriteLine("THis is staticcc");

    b = new B();
}

public static B b;
```

Comment: Thank you Patrick, some I understand while your code I didn't understood :( I am just learning.... thank you